# Python ** for negative numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. ** => operator is used for calculating exponential .

```
print(2 ** 3)  //8
print(-2 ** 3) //-8
print(-2 ** 2) //-4
```

It should print 4 only right ?

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with python determining the type of the variable used. If you cast the `-2` as int, the result is correct: `>>> print(int(-2) ** 2)
>>> 4`

Comment: I think here - operator in front 2 considered as unary operator , and ** operator is having higher precedence so first 2 ** 2 calculated first ,then unary operator will be applied . I am not sure if it correct or not . 
@Macko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [6.5. The power operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator). And more specifically:

> Thus, in an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): -1**2 results in -1.

Comment: left to right evaluation only happens right ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
print(-2 ** 2)
```

use this code

```
print(int(-2) ** 2)
```

Comment: just: `print( (-2) ** 2) `. so, `int` isn't needed here...